Getting MAICPP information via Microsoft (Partner Center) REST API
For an MSP working with Microsoft, I want to get all information regarding the MAICPP program (designations) via an API call. Preferably all information regarding the scores on the different designations and measurements (skilling, customer success and performance), but perhaps also the metrics that are underneath those scores.
However, I cannot find an API call that gives me this information. Is there an API that provides this kind of information?
I have already gone through the Microsoft Partner Center REST API, but could not find the right URLs. Also, the Graph API doesn't seem to be a great fit.
